# Limit length of headline in Editor

Tags: functions, editor

I`m searching for a function to limit the number of characters a user can type into the headline field in the editor.

Comment: What do you mean by headline field? Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: I`m talking about the editor field, where you type in the headline, the title of your article or page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add this function :

```
add_action('publish_post', 'wpse_105297_max_char');
function wpse_105297_max_char() {
   global $post;
   $title = $post->post_title;
   if (strlen($title) >= 100 )
    wp_die( "The max lenght is 100 for title" );
 }
```

This will prevent users from using too much longer titles.

Comment: Thank you. This works pretty well. Just added some usability.

`add_action('publish_post', 'wpse_105297_max_char');
function wpse_105297_max_char() {
   global $post;
   $title = $post->post_title;
   $id = $post->ID;
   $url = $bloginfo->url;
   if (strlen($title) >= 100 )
    wp_die( "The max lenght is 100 for title<br /><br />
    <a href=\"$url/wp-admin/post.php?post=$id&action=edit\">back to edit</a>." );

}`